# Keycloak - Multi/2FA Factor - OTP - QR Code - Custom Login Screen - Rest API

Tags: authentication, keycloak, user-registration, keycloak-services, multi-factor-authentication

I have **my own Login page where user enters username/password.**
This username/password are used to login through Keycloak Rest API.

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/token

```
input - {username,password,grant_type,client_secret,client_id}
```

And in response i get `access token`.

Now i wish to enable Authenticator (`Google Authenticator`). I have enabled it from backend. Now if user wishes to login thorugh my application, my login page i need to get below details.

1.) Somehow i need to include QR Code that appears on keycloak login page post username/password validation to show on my login screen for the first time login once user enter username/password. So do we have any API which return Keycloak QR code image in response.

2.) Subsequent login i will have OTP field, so need a REST api to pass OTP along with username/password.

Please help with REST API if keycloak has any. Integrating through Javascript.

Similar flow as described in use case 1 [here](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013254.html)

Just want to use keycloak as a database, doing all operation for me, input will be my screen. I do want redirection of URL's while login in and yet should be standalone deployed.

Comment: Keycloak already has [OTP integration](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_admin/topics/authentication/otp-policies.html). Have you considered using the authorization code flow (log in using the keycloak page) instead of the direct access grant (which is not recommended, BTW)? Keep in mind you can customize keycloak's login page. Otherwise, you might be doing quite much extra work and entering bugs/security issues, just to proxify one feature KC already has through your app.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Hey, i have checked this page, i am able to integrate using admin login UI validating against Google Authenticator, i still wish to create my own UI and have to render QR code based on keycloak response.

Comment: I have also created ticket [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-7345?jql=text%20~%20%22QR%20Code%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)

Answer (score 13):

I've managed to implement this through the rest API of Keycloak. To realize this, you need to extend Keycloak yourself with a SPI. To do this create your own Java project and extend `org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProvider` and `org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory`. You can find more information in the official docs (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions), github examples and other stack overflow posts how to do this.

Once you got this up and running you can implement it like this:

```
@GET
@Path("your-end-point-to-fetch-the-qr")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public YourDtoWithSecretAndQr get2FASetup(@PathParam("username") final String username) {
    final RealmModel realm = this.session.getContext().getRealm();
    final UserModel user = this.session.users().getUserByUsername(username, realm);
    final String totpSecret = HmacOTP.generateSecret(20);
    final String totpSecretQrCode = TotpUtils.qrCode(totpSecret, realm, user);
    return new YourDtoWithSecretAndQr(totpSecret, totpSecretQrCode);
}

@POST
@Path("your-end-point-to-setup-2fa")
@Consumes("application/json")
public void setup2FA(@PathParam("username") final String username, final YourDtoWithData dto) {
    final RealmModel realm = this.session.getContext().getRealm();
    final UserModel user = this.session.users().getUserByUsername(username, realm);
    final OTPCredentialModel otpCredentialModel = OTPCredentialModel.createFromPolicy(realm, dto.getSecret(), dto.getDeviceName());
    CredentialHelper.createOTPCredential(this.session, realm, user, dto.getInitialCode(), otpCredentialModel);
}
```

The secret received with the GET must be send back with the POST. The initial code is the one from your 2FA app (e.g. Google Authenticator). The QR code is a string which can be displayed in an `img` with src `'data:image/png;base64,' + qrCodeString;`

Comment: would you mind sharing your SPI extension code on Github? We're implementing the same thing right now. Thanks!

Comment: Since we're not an open-source company I cannot do this. But the code is quite similar to this: https://github.com/conciso/keycloak-spi-example. The hardest part for me was not the Factory / java code, but the jboss runtime loading of external code (pom versions must match with scope provided and jboss-deployment-structure.xml in resources must be correct)

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but I've recently been looking at something similar, and so thought it would be potentially valuable to share what I have found for others who may be looking into this and wondered what the possibilities are.

---

**TL;DR**
You can only really use the existing Keycloak actions to do this or embed the user account management page found at https://{keycloak server URL}/auth/realms/{realm name}/account in an iframe. That's it, I'm afraid. In my opinion it is currently best to just assign actions directly to accounts or use the Credential Reset emails to assign actions; both of these can be done via the Admin API if desired:

Send Credential Reset email containing assigned actions:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_executeactionsemail

Set actions directly on the account (include the actions in the requiredActions portion of the user JSON that you send in the body to the endpoint):
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_updateuser

---

Background is that as part of a project that I have been working on we wanted to see if we could have an integrated way for users to set up their initial password and OTP device when a new account has been created for them, since the default method of sending them an email from Keycloak using the "Credential Reset" functionality has the limitations that a) it doesn't provide a link to the application itself unless you override the theme, and if you have multiple instances of the application for different users you have no way of knowing which instance to provide the link for, so may have to end up including a list of them, and b) it often doesn't feel truly native to the application, even with changes to the theme. If you're sensible though, I'd suggest you stop and just use this functionality - please see the TL;DR section above for details.

So, in short there is NO API endpoint for receiving a QR code to set up an OTP device. There are two places, however, where the QR code can be retrieved from - the OTP device setup screen when you log in as a user who has had a "Configure OTP" action assigned to their account, and the user's own account management screen.

The first option of the Configure OTP action screen is a non-starter. It only shows up when you log in, and so by definition the user has to log in to Keycloak via the Keycloak login page in order to trigger the page to be displayed. At this point you're already on a Keycloak page instead of one of your app's pages, and so unless you can get very creative with changes to these Keycloak pages via a custom theme, tapping into this page isn't really an option.

The second option is more interesting, but far from ideal. Every user who has logged in has access to an account management page that can be found at https://{keycloak server URL}/auth/realms/{realm name}/account. This page allows you to do things like change your name, password, etc. and it also allows you to add an OTP device if you don't already have one, or delete any existing OTP devices associated with your account. This OTP device tab of the account management page can be reached directly via https://{keycloak server URL}/auth/realms/{realm name}/account/totp.

As I mentioned, there isn't an API that you can access to view the QR code that shows up on this page. The only way it is accessible is via the GET request to https://{keycloak server URL}/auth/realms/{realm name}/account/totp, which returns the HTML for the page I've already mentioned. Okay great, so can we scrape the QR code programmatically and then put it in our own page on our application? Err, no, not really. You see, whilst a lot of the Keycloak API endpoints rightly allow you to send a bearer token (e.g. access token) in the authorization header to access and endpoint, this page will not accept a bearer token as a means of authentication/authorization. Instead it uses a session cookie that is locked down to the Keycloak URL. This cookie is set when you log in to your application via the Keycloak login page, and so is available to this account management page when you navigate to it, having already logged in, and since the account management page uses the same server and domain name as the original Keycloak login page, it has access to the cookie and can let you in. This cookie cannot be sent by your application to e.g. your own REST API to then programmatically call the account management page and scrape the QR code, because your application doesn't have access to it for good security reasons. This might be something you can change in Keycloak somewhere, but if there is I would strongly recommend against changing it.

So if we can't scrape the page from our own server, can we do something on the front-end? Well, as mentioned, your application doesn't have access to the session cookie but if you make a request (e.g. using fetch or axios) in your front-end JavaScript to the account management page then that request will send the cookie along with it, so that could work right? Umm, well actually you will get hit with an error message in this scenario due to CORS. CORS is Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing and in order to allow the Keycloak page to be accessed then you would have to open up the settings on the server to allow it to be accessed from your website's address. I've seen some articles that look at how you can open up your CORS settings on Keycloak if you wish but I'd be very nervous about doing this. I don't know enough about the internals of Keycloak and how it operates to comment on how much of a security risk this is, but I certainly wouldn't recommend it. There some information here ([Keycloak angular No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051923/keycloak-angular-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)) on changing the "Web Origins" setting of your application's Keycloak client, but this opens up your application to some serious potential abuse. There is also the MAJOR issue that even if you scraped the QR code, the device isn't actually added to the user's account (even though it appears in the authenticator app) until you enter a code into the page that the QR code is on and click Save. Since there isn't an API endpoint that you can use to complete this operation, I therefore don't think that this option is viable either. I've tried out whether or not you can use the token retrieval endpoint at https://{keycloak server URL}/auth/realms/{realm name}/protocol/openid-connect/token to see if making a request with your username/password/otp code will somehow "register" your device and complete the process, but although you can get a token this way, and it doesn't complain about the otp code, it doesn't actually take any notice of the code because as far as it's concerned the user's account doesn't have a device registered with it. So we have to use the form on the account management page in order to complete this registration process.

So the final way of possibly doing this is.... an iframe. Sorry, yeah it's rubbish but that's all your left with. You can have the iframe point at your account management page, and because the user is logged in then they will be able to see the contents from your application's page. You can use relative positioning, fixed width and height and remove scroll bars to ensure that you ONLY show the QR code and the fields for the one time code, device name, and the Save/Cancel buttons. This, sadly, seems to be the only option at the moment, and due to how nasty and unreliable iframes can be in general - they certainly don't feel native to your application, and you'll need to override your Keycloak theme to get the page in question to look more like your app - I'd recommend steering clear of this and using the standard approach of using Keycloak actions and the Admin API instead.

If you've made it this far, congratulations, you win at Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, see the answer below =)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Sadly doesn't help in my particular situation as I'm working with a managed instance that I don't control - hence why I steered clear of the SPI route - but hoping your answer helps someone else :-)