# Spring Boot with React and Keycloak: redirect to Keycloak's login page fails due to CORS error (no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set)

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm working on the following setup:

- Frontend: React on localhost:3000
- Backend: Spring Boot on localhost:8080
- OIDC endpoint: Keycloak 21+ as Docker container (tried different
  versions) on localhost:8090

As I'm a backend dev and have little to no experience with React, I wanted to let Spring handle all the authentication and authorization against Keycloak. Thus, I've configured:

```
spring:
  security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        keycloak:
          clientId: <my id>
          clientSecret: <my secret>
          scope: openid
      provider:
        keycloak:
          issuerUri: <my issuer uri>
          user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

and set the oauth2 config:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
            .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .exceptionHandling(customizer -> customizer.accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler()))
            .authorizeHttpRequests((customizer) -> customizer.requestMatchers(
                        "/oauth2/login",
                        "/oauth2/logout/success",
                        "/oauth2/error",
                        
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).oauth2Login(configurer -> {
                configurer.userInfoEndpoint(customizer -> customizer.userAuthoritiesMapper(customGrantedAuthoritiesMapper()));
                configurer.loginPage("/oauth2/login");
                configurer.defaultSuccessUrl("/oauth2/success");
                configurer.failureUrl("/oauth2/error");
            });
}
```

When I access some protected endpoint (let's say /api/test) from React, Spring sends a redirect (per Location-header) to

> http://localhost:8080/oauth2/login

which then redirects to

> http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/keycloak

which redirects to Keycloak on

> http://localhost:8090/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=my-client-id&scope=openid&state=my-state&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8086/login/oauth2/code/keycloak&nonce=my-nonce*

When calling it directly from the browser, it works fine and I see the login form, can login and access my protected resources afterwards with the right roles set into the principal. But as soon as the request's origin is my frontend webapp, the last redirect to Keycloak fails because of missing CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Of course I followed the manual and set the valid resource urls as well as web origins inside Keycloak's client settings. But nothing worked, I tried to

- set the frontend url without trailing slashes
- set + and added http://localhost:3000/* to the valid redirect urls
- set * as a test, even though it would open security loopholes

Nothing worked, I tried multiple solutions like those on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051923/keycloak-angular-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present), [Discourse (1)](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/access-control-allow-origin-header-missing/328), [Discourse (2)](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-preflight-missing-allow-origin-header/7940) and multiple others, but to no avail. Unfortunately Keycloak changed a bit in the past (of course), so most articles are outdated. But finally I've stumbled upon [this resource](https://github.com/jangaraj/keycloak-cors-issue-debugging?tab=readme-ov-file) saying in point 7 that this CORS error indicates "wrong backend/API implementation or used flow".

So long story short: has anyone managed to get it running like described? Should I change my architecture to let React handle the authentication with Keycloak, sending JWT token to Spring instead?

Thank you very much for your opinions and insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to use a brand new navigation to follow the redirection to Keycloak authorization endpoint: if setting `windows.location` instead of letting the browser follow the redirect, you'll have Keycloak as origin (you won't be in a cross origin situation anymore).

For that, you need to change the status of the response sent by Spring from `302` to something in the `2xx` range (to follow to the location header programmatically in react instead of letting the browser handle it).

See [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2) I wrote for details.

Comment: Thank you. A very detailed article I need to read carefully. The full BFF approach seems a little overkill for me, but I'm not yet sure what I need 

Comment: Thank you again! 
I managed to get it working with your tips. 

If anyone stumbles upon this issue again in the future: first I tried to just catch the 302 in a response interceptor of axios and set window.location there, but that didn't work because the browser follows the redirect automatically. 

Then I customized Spring to send 201 instead and checked that in the frontend.